# How to stop a js promise.all() on a condition?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have this piece of code

```
 let promiseList = []

    for (let i in data) {
        let promise = checkIfMember(data[i].tg_id, chatId).then(res => {
            if (res) {
                //if the user has a undefined username it won't be rained
                if (data[i].username != "undefined") {
                    console.log(data[i].username)
                    members.push([data[i].tg_id, data[i].username])
                }
            }
        }).catch(err => {
            console.log(err)
        })
        promiseList.push(promise)
    }

    return Promise.all(promiseList).then((res) => {
        //list of members that are in the room , we randomize it before returning
        shuffleArray(members)
        if(numberOfUsers > members.length){
            return[false, members.length]
        }else{
            members = members.slice(0,numberOfUsers)
            return [true, members]
        }
    });
```

Basically I have a promise list that is being filled. And then all of them are executed with a promiseAll. The problem is that I dont want all of them to execute, I want to to do something like this:

```
let promiseList = []
    let validmembers = 0;
    for (let i in data) {
        let promise = checkIfMember(data[i].tg_id, chatId).then(res => {
            if (res) {
                //if the user has a undefined username it won't be rained
                if (data[i].username != "undefined") {
                    console.log(data[i].username)
                    members.push([data[i].tg_id, data[i].username])
                    //stop there the execution
                    validmembers++;
                    if(validmembers == numberOfUsers){
                        return;
                    }
                }
            }
        }).catch(err => {
            console.log(err)
        })
        promiseList.push(promise)
    }

    return Promise.all(promiseList).then((res) => {
        //list of members that are in the room , we randomize it before returning
        shuffleArray(members)
        if(numberOfUsers > members.length){
            return[false, members.length]
        }else{
            members = members.slice(0,numberOfUsers)
            return [true, members]
        }
    });
```

But the problem is that the promises are async, so the promiselist filling doesnt stop.
How would I solve this?

Comment: promise all does not actually execute promises, it only adds a wrapper to them that resolves once all of them resolved

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears you want the `members` array to have no more than `numberOfUsers` entries in it due to the promises. Since the promises run asynchronously you can't stop the `checkIfMember` function from being called, but inside of its `then` function you could avoid accumulating more members like this:

```js
// don't use `!== "undefined"` unless it can actually be the string "undefined"
if (data[i].username) {  
  if (members.length < numberOfUsers) {
    console.log(data[i].username);
    members.push([data[i].tg_id, data[i].username]);
  }
}
```

By only pushing to `members` when it's not yet full you will avoid adding more than `numberOfUsers` and don't need to do the `slice` later.

If instead you want to avoid the entire promise work when enough have been collected, then you can serialize them like this:

```js
async function yourFunction() {
  for (let i in data) {
    if (members.length < numberOfUsers) {
      // don't continue to the next 'i' until this one is done
      await checkIfMember(data[i].tg_id, chatId)
        .then(res => {
          if (res) {
            //if the user has a undefined username it won't be rained
            if (data[i].username != "undefined") {
              console.log(data[i].username);
              members.push([data[i].tg_id, data[i].username]);
            }
          }
        })
        .catch(err => {
          console.log(err);
        });
    } else {
      break; // no need to continue once members is full 
    }
  }

  return [true, members];
}
```

Comment: It might be valid to not fill the array and avoid the slice. But the problem is executing the promise X times, I dont want to abuse the api, thats the main problem, and that condition will still execute all the promises. I want them to stop executing once the treshold is reached

Comment: the only way to do what you want would be to serialize the promises rather than kicking them all off then waiting for them to finish. Would you be okay with only starting one once the previous has completed?

Comment: yes it would be fine too, but I dont really know how to implement it